# Need help forming a regex pattern matcher

Tags: java, android, regex

My String to parse is an http response with the separation of vertical bars '|' colons ':'
and commas ','

```
"1701|919422522891:224c1214-bb95-414d-ba76-77db95370545,1701|918275004333:5e93a439-2644-4455-9f01-f27e6cf0cde6"
```

I have made an attempt to parse with the following code

```
public void split2(){
    String input = "1701|919422522891:224c1214-bb95-414d-ba76-77db95370545," +
                   "1701|918275004333:5e93a439-2644-4455-9f01-f27e6cf0cde6";

    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\|.*?\\:\\,").matcher(input);
    int nr = 0;
    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group());
    }
}
```

UPDATE - WORKING CODE

The split method works well

```
  public String[] split(String regex,String input)
    {
        input = "1701|919422522891:224c1214-bb95-414d-ba76-77db95370545," +
                "1701|918275004333:5e93a439-2644-4455-9f01-f27e6cf0cde6";
        regex = "\\||:|," ;


        String[] soso = Pattern.compile(regex).split(input, input.length());

            for(String s :soso){
                Log.e("",s.toString());
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: What's your expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of match you can easily do a split.

```
\||:|,
```

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/vN3sH3/28

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("[^|]*\\|[^:]*:[^,]*,").matcher(input);
```

**Explanation:** This regex `"[^|]*\\|[^:]*:[^,]*,"` means:

1. `[^|]*` - Match 0 or more characters before a pipe
2. `\\|` - Match a pipe
3. `[^:]*` - Match 0 or more characters before a colon
4. `:` - Match a colon
5. `[^,]*` - Match 0 or more characters before a comma
6. `,` - Match a coma